# Why does findUser.username return unidentified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my console.log the findUser.username is printed but the error is still there. Can some one help me with that please. Thank you.

```
const auth_user = [
  {
    username: "amylussie",
    password: "123456789",
    name: "Amy Lusita",
    phone: "04055631",
    address: "23 UL fasdf",
    bestfriend: "Mark"
  }
];


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setUser: (myUser) => dispatch(action_checkUser(myUser))
  };
};

const Search = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const onSearch = () => {
    const findUser = auth_user.find((user) =>
      user.username.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
    console.log(findUser.username);
    if (findUser.username !== search) {
      console.log("Please try again");
    }

    props.setUser(findUser);
  };
```

Comment: Can you add your demo [here](https://react.new). Codewise looks fine. Might be mistake at somewhere else

Comment: I just did it. Please check

Comment: You have to share url

Comment: I mean I just add my demo to the link you posted. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes what I say you have to share that link, The link I share is starter as soon as you save the code. It will create your sandbox link which you need to share here

Comment: What is the error being reported? Can you provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and include a set of reproduction steps that we can trace through your code with?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **search** has value `amylussie` otherwise, it can't find  `username: "amylussie"` and return undefined

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

> The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. > Otherwise, undefined is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `findUser.username !== search` will *always* be true unless the `search` value *exactly* matches `findUser.username`, i.e. when a user's search input is "amylussie".

An improvement may be to simply check the result of [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) *didn't* return `undefined` for not finding a match.

```
const Search = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");

  const onSearch = () => {
    const findUser = auth_user.find((user) =>
      user.username.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );

    if (!findUser) {
      console.log("Please try again");
      return; // <-- return early
    }
    console.log(findUser.username);

    props.setUser(findUser);
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

[image: Edit why-does-finduser-username-return-unidentified]